# How to start an Android service by sending an intent using Robotium?

Tags: android, instrumentation, robotium

I want to write a test case that spans over multiple activities(3 to be precise). I need to start a service which will be used by the all 3 activities. How could I start the service from my TestCase using Solo? Also after the service starts would I have to take some special steps to bind the activities to the service? Sorry I am an Android noob.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what "Solo" is, besides the name of a city on the island of Java and the surname of a Star Wars character.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your service along with your app. you will not have anything to worry about one the activity launches. Alternatively you could add a 4. activity which starts the service and then trigger this activity from Robotium prior to the "real" test.